# Delete index using rest/spread operator using JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following scenario where I need an index deleted.

JS:

```
this.state = {
      rangeValue: this.props.rangeSlider && [
        this.props.rangeValue[0],
        this.props.rangeValue[1],
        this.props.rangeValue[2]
      ],
    };


<Range 
   defaultValue={
   this.props.rangeValue[2] ? [...this.state.rangeValue] : [...this.state.rangeValue] //minus last index in my array (this.props.rangeValue[2])
            }
          />
```

Comment: Why does it have to use the spread operator? Use the `.slice()` method: `this.state.rangeValue.slice(0, -1)`

Comment: What is `<range`

Comment: @Barmar perhaps they don't want the initial array modified.

Comment: @MathewBerg slice doesn't modify the original array. Before ES6 slices we used `this.state.rangeValue.slice()` to make a copy of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the last element by using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
this.state.rangeValue.slice(0,-1);
```

Your code :

```
<Range
  defaultValue={
    this.props.rangeValue[2] ? [...this.state.rangeValue] : this.state.rangeValue.slice(0, -1)
  }
/>
```

Comment: Much Thanks @Taki

Comment: Spoke to soon. Getting this error with that condition: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node."

Comment: @MathewBerg [no, it does not](https://jsfiddle.net/d469jcg8/) , `slice` [returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)